# Get image size when it loads from an extern URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, size

I need to know the image size when it loads from an extern URL because the project needs to resize the image div.

I need to do something like this:

```
<img id="imglegend'+layername+'" src="url_to_an_extern_host" />
```

And, using Javascript and JQuery:

```
$('#imglegend'+layername).ready(function(){
   var h = $('#imglegend'+layername);
   // Resize image div container
});
```

But this didn't work. Is it possible to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That should be handled by styling not programmatically. `<img>` by default resizes to image size so your other formatting is not correct.

Comment: But this project loads images dinamically, and I need to know image size dinamically too. Thanks Aliostad!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#imglegend').load(function(){
   var w =    $(this).width();
   var h =    $(this).height();
   alert(w); alert(h);
}).error(function (){
   $(this).remove();//remove image if it fails to load// or what ever u want
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Images don't have a `ready` event. They do however have a `load` event:

```
$('#imglegend'+layername).load(function(){
   alert(this.width);
});
```

EDIT: BTW, you need to make sure that the image isn't loaded before you attach the event handler. You'll wither need to assign the `src` in your script after assigning the handler instead of in your HTML, or assign the handler in the `onload` HTML instead.

Comment: My mistake then. I'm a little newbie with JS already. Val's answer is what I was lookin for. Thanks for your tip too, RoToRa!